# Adding a new item with submenus on google document's context menu using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-docs, google-docs-api, right-click

I am currently writing a google chrome extension. I'd like to add a new menu item with sub-menu items under it, on the google document's context menu using chrome extension. How can I achieve this using `content_script` from a chrome.

I have already looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212111/adding-a-new-item-on-google-documents-context-menu-using-chrome-extension) and was successful in adding the top-level menu item. But I now need sub-menu items under it. I looked at the HTML elements using dev-tools by hovering over the `Formatting Options` menu, which has sub-menu:

[image]

But the sub-menu item seems to be wrapped in its own div element and couldn't quite figure out how it is linked to its parent menu.